# Gratis JavaScript library to fake TV noise / interference

Tags: gratis, javascript

Related : [Animating canvas to look like tv noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003491/animating-canvas-to-look-like-tv-noise)

I want to have a small portion of a web page look like it has "TV noise" (if you can think of a better English phrase, please update), and am looking for a gratis script.

The more customization, the better.

[image]

Comment: Maybe some of the whitenoise generation libraries?
https://github.com/josephg/noisejs

Comment: Upvote, but note "if you try and update an entire screen's worth of pixels, it'll be slow". I will use if only for a portion of the screen, so it might be usable. Worst case, I will code my own. But, why reinvent the wheel if a good library already exists?

Comment: As an aside - have you considered what proportion of people alive now wouldn't know what that actually was? ;))

Comment: Has Hollywood? Has TV? Just to test some CSS & Angular skills (including unit test), I want to code one of those "walls of information" that you often see in TV & Movies.  A few faces, some number & text scrolling past, maps, satellite views, etc (any suggestions). It seems that there is almost always one display which is "on the blink", so I thought to add one too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following looks very realistic for a "no signal" situation  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-background-like-tv-noise-in-a-canvas/

[image]

Showing my age, this also used to be called "**snow**".

For bad signal, this is possibly better https://codepen.io/ashandrien/pen/nVjPgj

[image]

Comment: "`Showing my age, this also used to be called "snow"`".  When it happened, did you climb onto the roof to adjust the antenna/aerial?

Comment: that... and slapping the side or top of the TV to bring it back to its senses.

Comment: And trying to understand horizontal & vertical hold.  And the "remote control" was the youngest kid in the room, who was ordered to change the channel :-) Ah, happy days!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/bahamas10/tvstatic) looks promising

[image]

I am less keen on [this](https://github.com/loktar00/static-img)

[image]

I will also look into [this](https://github.com/JBrooksCS/static-tv) and [this](https://github.com/scottleitch/JavaScript-TV-Static) and continue to search and will finally post an answer. Although, hopefully someone will bet me to it :-)